# Wordpress Gravity Form response issue

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am working on a WordPress site that uses a gravity form. The gravity form has 20 questions, after a user fills it out they press submit and then a page loads saying the form has been submitted. The form submits to an AWS API that checks the form and returns a percent correct to the gravity form inside the admin panel.

I am trying to get that result to display on the website so that the user can see. I don't know how to get the response. When I try to access the AWS endpoint through curl or Postman, I get forbidden errors. I am using the endpoint and the API key listed in the gravity forms settings

This is the latest curl I tried (I changed the base64 code for this example):

```
curl -X GET \
  https://reproductivehealth.adrianmiddletonfwd.co.uk/wp-json/gf/v2/entries \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic WRThbTpaWlVZcEtoVlFQdndDMTVybktDZZz=' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

I get this error:

```
{"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.","data":{"status":401}}
```

I've also tried to create a post using the API endpoint and API key provided within the form settings. I don't know what else to try, I just need to get that result.